# How to get "x" datatime.timedeltas from one array into one output?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have a script getting input from 'x' zipfiles. From each zipfile I get a datatime.timedelta object that I convert into minutes and seconds in the format: average time spent on session is 24min 0s in 'x' pdf's.

Example: from one pdf I get 24min 0s and another 28min 0s. I want to create a new pdf with the output: average time spent on session 26min 0s (because that is the average time spend between 24min and 28min).

I have script creating an array with [datetime.timedelta(seconds=1462, microseconds=936503), datetime.timedelta(seconds=1706, microseconds=983165)]. I use .append to push 0:24:22.936503 and 0:28:26.983165 into my array.

How can I merge this two datatime.timedelta elements in my array so I can find the average time spent? I would like to end up with the format  x:xx:xx.xxxxxx that I later use the code ({x:xx:xx.xxxxxx.total_seconds()/60:.0f} min {x:xx:xx.xxxxxx.total_seconds()%60:.0f} s) to get the output on the pdf that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the average of a list of `timedelta` objects basically the same way you would with a list of numbers - sum them together and divide by the number of elements.

For example:

```py
deltas = [timedelta(minutes=30), timedelta(minutes=20)]

avg = sum(deltas, start=timedelta()) / len(deltas)

print(f"{avg.total_seconds()/60:.0f} min {avg.total_seconds()%60:.0f} s")
```

this gives:

```
25 min 0 s
```

Note that we have to pass `start=timedelta()` to the `sum` function (see [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum))

Presumably this is because `sum` behaves like a special case of [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) function - i.e. it needs a starting value and its default of `0` is not compatible with timedeltas, so we give it the timedelta equivalent of zero as the `start` value.